# how to insert number like in stack and delete like pop

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray

I am using buttons and I assigned tag `0` to `10` . Then I made an action to get the clicked button's tag, and now I want to display the tag in a label . Also I have a cancel button `C`. If user wants to delete any number, he can click `C` button that I want to remove number from the label .

This is my screenshot to touch the number

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Ezywire";

    addnum=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    numbber=[[NSString alloc]init];
}

- (IBAction)NumberAction:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tagvalue = [sender tag];
    NSString *current=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)tagvalue]; 
     [addnum addObject:current];

    NSString *temp;
    for ( int i=0; i<[addnum count]; i++) {

       numbber=[numbber stringByAppendingString:[addnum objectAtIndex:i]];

    }

    NSLog(@"data===%@",numbber);

    ValueLable.text= numbber;

}
```

But in the label I am getting repeated number like this. How to implement this.

For example if user enters 2 then in the label

```
2
```

then he enters 7 then in the label

```
27
```

then he entered 9 then in the label

```
279
```

........ like this .

If user clicks `C`, then it remove from label last value is (last value removed)

```
27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `numbber` is initialized when the view is loaded, and never gets cleared again. However, each time a button is pressed, the whole `addnum` of digits gets appended to `num` again, creating repeated digits.

Fix this by removing `num` as an instance variable, making it a local to `NumberAction:` method, and setting it to an empty string every time the number is pressed.

Since you are planning to support the clearing action as well, you should make a private method that combines the digits from `addnum` array into a string. This way your `NumberAction:` and `ClearAction` would share the code that formats the array and sets the label. Your `NumberAction:` method would append a number and call `FormatAndSetLabel`, while the `ClearAction` method would remove the last digit if it is available, and call `FormatAndSetLabel` as well:

```
- (IBAction)NumberAction:(id)sender {
    NSInteger tagvalue = [sender tag];
    NSString *current=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)tagvalue]; 
    [addnum addObject:current];
    [self FormatAndSetLabel];
}

- (IBAction)ClearAction:(id)sender {
    if (!addnum.count) return;
    [addnum removeLastObject];
    [self FormatAndSetLabel];
}


-(void)FormatAndSetLabel {
    NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString string];
    for ( int i=0; i<[addnum count]; i++) {
        [temp appendString:addnum[i]];
    }
    ValueLable.text= temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it might be interesting for you to have a look at Paul's Hegarty Stanford iOS development course (iPad and iPhone Application Development, Fall 2011)

https://itunes.apple.com/ru/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10

Calculator app is used here as an example. Must see for the beginners.